# Git rollback from two commits ago

Tags: git

I branched from master a few days ago and have made two subsequent commits to the `newbranch`.

Later, I noticed that a file in the first commit I made should not have been changed.  I haven't pushed anything to the master branch yet, all my changes are in `newbranch`.  How can I rollback this one file in `newbranch` to where it stood when I originally branched from master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this depending on the result you want.

The [answer from euphoria83](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19669480/1256452) does this...

At start, you have a commit history that looks like this (each letter represents a commit):

```
A - B - C          <-- master
          \
            D
              \
                E  <-- HEAD=newbranch
```

Commit `C` is what was in master when you started.  You made some changes and committed (creating `D`) and then some more and committed (creating `E`).

Now you run `git checkout HEAD~1`.  This updates your working directory to match commit D, and gives you a "detached HEAD" (shades of the French Revolution!) that points directly to commit `D`, rather than containing a branch-name:

```
A - B - C          <-- master
          \
            D      <-- HEAD
              \
                E  <-- newbranch
```

(This form of checkout, `git checkout <branch-name-or-rev>`, tells git to change what `HEAD` names.  The `<rev>` in this case, `HEAD~1`, means "look up what commit HEAD names and move back one", so this says to move back one from commit `E`.  As this is a specific `<rev>` and not a branch name, it also has that "detach HEAD" effect.)

Now you run `git checkout HEAD~1 filename`.  To be more explicit to git you can say `git checkout HEAD~1 -- filename`.  The `--` says "remaining arguments are file names, not branch or revision names"—if you leave out the `--`, git tries to guess whether it's a branch name or a file name.

This form of `checkout`, with the `-- filename` argument, does something rather different: it says to look up revision `HEAD~1` as usual, but this time, don't *change* `HEAD`, just extract the given file.  Since `HEAD` now names revision `D`, git backs up one more, to revision `C`, and extracts the version of file `filename` from that revision and puts it in the working directory.

(Note that the branch name `master` *also* names revision `C`, so you could have written `git checkout master -- filename` at this point.)

Next, `git commit -a --amend` tells git to add any changed files—in this case, you don't actually need it, but in general this would add other files you've fixed-up—and then do an "amend commit".  An "amend commit" means "create a new commit, but make its parent commit the same as our parent commit".  This creates a new commit—let's call it `D'` whose parent is `C`.  As always, the new commit becomes the `HEAD`.  Since `HEAD` is detached, no branch name moves yet.  The resulting commit tree looks like this:

```
A - B - C               <-- master
        | \
        \   D
          \   \
            \   E       <-- newbranch
              \
                D'      <-- HEAD
```

The files in `D'` are the same as those in `D`, except for file `filename`, which is now the same as in revision `C`.

Next, `git cherry-pick newbranch` says to get the revision named by `newbranch`—that's revision `E`—and make the same changes to the HEAD revision, as a new commit (let's call it `E'`):

```
A - B - C               <-- master
        | \
        \   D
          \   \
            \   E       <-- newbranch
              \
                D' - E' <-- HEAD
```

Now you just need to give a branch name to `HEAD`.  It's then safe to delete `newbranch`, or rename it out of the way, and then rename `newnew` to `newbranch`:

```
git checkout -b newnew          # now HEAD=newnew which points to E'
git branch -m newbranch oldnew  # rename out of the way
git branch -m newnew newbranch  # and rename newnew to newbranch
```

(you can shorten this a bit but let's go on to...)

---

There's an easier way to do the same thing.  Just run `git rebase -i master`.  This says to rebase the current branch (`newbranch`) using `master` as its "upstream".  That is, find all the commits after `master` (which means, `D` and `E`) and rebase those onto `master` (which is where they were based before).  Without `-i` this would be silly—rebase `D` and `E` to exactly the way they were before, that's just an expensive way to do nothing—but with `-i` git opens up an editor on a series of commands.  The commands will `pick` commits `D` and `E`.  Change the `pick` for commit `D` to `edit`, and write out the file.

The rebase will then cherry-pick `D` for you and stop and let you amend the commit.  At the shell, enter:

```
git checkout master -- filename
git commit -a --amend
```

as before, and save the amended commit, which becomes `D'`.  Then run:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Git will now cherry-pick commit `E`, giving commit `E'`.  It's now all done so the rebase finishes, and branch `newbranch` has the commits you want.

---

The [answer from ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19669462/1256452) does something different.  It contains the same `git checkout master -- filename` (spelled `filepath`) but no rebase-like sequence.

So, as before, you start with this:

```
A - B - C             <-- master
          \
            D
              \
                E     <-- HEAD=newbranch
```

Then you extract the version of `filename` that is in revision `C` into the working directory.  If you now `git commit` (or `git commit -a`, same thing in this particular case—git this is because the above `checkout` writes the extracted rev-C file into the staging area first), you'll get a new commit `F` that changes file `filename` back to the way it was in `C`.

In other words, commits `D` and `E` will still have the change to the file; new commit `F` will undo the change.

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout master -- filepath`

Answer (score 1):

On new_branch:

```
git checkout HEAD~1
git checkout HEAD~1 file_not_needed
git commit -a --amend
git cherry-pick new_branch
git branch -f new_branch HEAD
```

Comment: That will leave you on a "detached HEAD" that looks like a branch, so you probably want one more step, to give the new branch a name.